# Access denied to login to original node id

Tags: 7, users, redirection

Scenario is this:

- User sent a link to a website where they must be authenticated to view content.
- User clicks link.
- They have an account but their session has expired so they get 403 access denied page.
- They login.
- The ideal outcome is they are redirected to the original link they tried to access.

I can get a login form to show on the 403 page but can't redirect to the node.

Has anyone any experience of this?

Comment: "can't redirect to the node" - what have you tried to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

[Login Destination](http://drupal.org/project/login_destination) claims to do what you need:

> It is also possible to keep users on the currently visited page after logging in or out.

Comment: Thanks. Ended up using 'Redirect 403 to User Login' module – https://drupal.org/project/r4032login

Comment: @StephenWilson maybe you could write how it solved your question as another answer?